# Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series - error on 30min and 20min timeframe only

Tags: pine-script

This script works perfectly on every timeframe except 30min and 20min?

I get an error"Pine cannot determine the referencing length of a series"

Adding max_bars_back has no effect on this error...I have tried that and it doesn't fix the error

Wondering what could possibly be causing this?

I'm also trying to figure out how to show previous pivots, have a checkbox to show or hide them.

```
//@version=4
//maxBarsBack = 200
//max_bars_back = maxBarsBack
study(title="Pivot Points Standard +", shorttitle="Pivot Points Standard +", overlay = true)
//hide_historical = input(false, title="Hide Historical?")
// 
// author: QuantNomad
// date: 2019-07-28
// Traditional Pivot Points Alerts
// https://www.tradingview.com/u/QuantNomad/
// https://t.me/quantnomad
//

// Function outputs 1 when it's the first bar of the D/W/M/Y
is_newbar(res) =>
    ch = 0
    if(res == 'Y')
        t  = year(time('D'))
        ch := change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    else
        t = time(res)
        ch := change(t) != 0 ? 1 : 0
    ch

nround(x) => 
    n = x < 10 ? 3 : x < 100 ? 2 : x < 1000 ? 1 : 0
    round(x * pow(10, n)) / pow(10, n)

////////////
// INPUTS //
////////////
//
pp_period = input(title = "Period", type=input.string, defval="Auto", options = ['Day', 'Week', 'Month', 'Year', 'Auto'])

show_levels = input(true, type = input.bool, title = "Show Levels?")

pp_res = pp_period == 'Day' ? 'D' : pp_period == 'Week' ? 'W' : pp_period == 'Month' ? 'M' : pp_period == 'Auto' ? (timeframe.multiplier>=16 and timeframe.multiplier<=720?'W':timeframe.multiplier<=15?'D':timeframe.isdaily?'M':timeframe.isweekly?'Y':timeframe.ismonthly?'Y':'Y'):'Y' 

//pp_res1=timeframe.isintraday?'D':timeframe.isdaily?'W':timeframe.isweekly?'Y':timeframe.ismonthly?'Y':'Y'


/////////////////////
// Get HLC from HT //

// Calc High
high_cur = 0.0
high_cur := is_newbar(pp_res) ? high : max(high_cur[1], high)

phigh = 0.0
phigh := is_newbar(pp_res) ? high_cur[1] : phigh[1]

// Calc Low
low_cur = 0.0
low_cur := is_newbar(pp_res) ? low : min(low_cur[1], low)

plow = 0.0
plow := is_newbar(pp_res) ? low_cur[1] : plow[1]

// Calc Close
pclose = 0.0
pclose := is_newbar(pp_res) ? close[1] : pclose[1]

////////////////////////////////
// CALCULATE traditional pivots //

vPP = (phigh + plow + pclose) / 3
vR1 = vPP    + (vPP   - plow)
vS1 = vPP    - (phigh - vPP)
vR2 = vPP    + (phigh - plow)
vS2 = vPP    - (phigh - plow)
vR3 = phigh  + 2 * (vPP   - plow) 
vS3 = plow   - 2 * (phigh - vPP) 
plongstop=(vPP+vS1)/2
pshortstop=(vPP+vR1)/2 
//////////////
// PLOTTING //

bars_sinse = 0
bars_sinse := is_newbar(pp_res) ? 0 : bars_sinse[1] + 1

//plot(bars_sinse)

////////////////////////
// PLOT PIVOTS LEVELS //

vpp_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vPP, bar_index, vPP, color=color.blue, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vs1_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vS1, bar_index, vS1, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vs2_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vS2, bar_index, vS2, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vs3_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vS3, bar_index, vS3, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vr1_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vR1, bar_index, vR1, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vr2_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vR2, bar_index, vR2, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vr3_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], vR3, bar_index, vR3, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
plongstop_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], plongstop, bar_index, plongstop, color=color.black, style =  line.style_dashed, extend = extend.right)
pshortstop_p = line.new(bar_index[bars_sinse], pshortstop, bar_index, pshortstop, color=color.black, style =  line.style_dashed, extend = extend.right)
// delete previous lines in the same period
if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    line.delete(vpp_p[1])
    line.delete(vs1_p[1]) 
    line.delete(vs2_p[1])  
    line.delete(vs3_p[1])  
    line.delete(vr1_p[1]) 
    line.delete(vr2_p[1])  
    line.delete(vr3_p[1]) 

// delete entend for the old lines
if (is_newbar(pp_res))
    line.set_extend(vpp_p[1], extend.none)
    line.set_extend(vs1_p[1], extend.none) 
    line.set_extend(vs2_p[1], extend.none)  
    line.set_extend(vs3_p[1], extend.none)  
    line.set_extend(vr1_p[1], extend.none) 
    line.set_extend(vr2_p[1], extend.none)  
    line.set_extend(vr3_p[1], extend.none) 

// Add labels
if (is_newbar(pp_res))
    label_vpp = label.new(bar_index, vPP, text=show_levels ? ("P"  + " " + tostring(nround(vPP))) : "P",  style= label.style_none)
//    if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    label.delete(label_vpp[1])
    label_vs1 = label.new(bar_index, vS1, text=show_levels ? ("S1" + " " + tostring(nround(vS1))) : "S1", style= label.style_none)
//    if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    label.delete(label_vs1[1]) 
    label_vs2 = label.new(bar_index, vS2, text=show_levels ? ("S2" + " " + tostring(nround(vS2))) : "S2", style= label.style_none)
//    if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    label.delete(label_vs2[1])  
    label_vs3 = label.new(bar_index, vS3, text=show_levels ? ("S3" + " " + tostring(nround(vS3))) : "S3", style= label.style_none)
//    if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    label.delete(label_vs3[1])  
    label_vr1 = label.new(bar_index, vR1, text=show_levels ? ("R1" + " " + tostring(nround(vR1))) : "R1", style= label.style_none)
//    if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    label.delete(label_vr1[1]) 
    label_vr2 = label.new(bar_index, vR2, text=show_levels ? ("R2" + " " + tostring(nround(vR2))) : "R2", style= label.style_none)
//    if (not is_newbar(pp_res)) 
    label.delete(label_vr2[1])  
    label_vr3 = label.new(bar_index, vR3, text=show_levels ? ("R3" + " " + tostring(nround(vR3))) : "R3", style= label.style_none)
//    if (is_newbar(pp_res))
    label.delete(label_vr3[1])
```

Comment: Here is the best answer:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_compilation_errors.html#pine-cannot-determine-the-referencing-length-of-a-series-try-using-max-bars-back-in-the-study-or-strategy-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it. Dunno why but Pine sometimes doesn't like the use of the history-referencing operator with `bar_index`, which is superfluous anyway:

```
//////////////
// PLOTTING //

var bars_sinse = 0
bars_sinse := is_newbar(pp_res) ? 0 : bars_sinse + 1

plotchar(bars_sinse, "bars_sinse", "", location.top)

// //////////////////////
// PLOT PIVOTS LEVELS //

vpp_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vPP, bar_index, vPP, color=color.blue, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vs1_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vS1, bar_index, vS1, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vs2_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vS2, bar_index, vS2, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vs3_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vS3, bar_index, vS3, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vr1_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vR1, bar_index, vR1, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vr2_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vR2, bar_index, vR2, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
vr3_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, vR3, bar_index, vR3, color=color.gray, style =  line.style_solid, extend = extend.right)
plongstop_p  = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, plongstop, bar_index, plongstop, color=color.black, style =  line.style_dashed, extend = extend.right)
pshortstop_p = line.new(bar_index - bars_sinse, pshortstop, bar_index, pshortstop, color=color.black, style =  line.style_dashed, extend = extend.right)
```

[image]

Comment: it works but after 10mins the script says "internal study error"...

Comment: Sry. Don't see any known problems with the code. If it's quantnomad's, you could consider asking him, or support.